# How to make paths visible in all project directories?

Tags: python, path

I have a project with the following structure

```
.
├── amr
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── amr_config.yaml
├── data
│   └── ...
├── notebooks
│   └── ...
└── pyproject.toml
```

And `amr_config.yaml` contains some paths like

```
DB_QUERIES_PATHS:
  REQUESTS: $REQUESTS|'./data/requests_data_query.sql'
```

Usually I run all the scripts from the root so it executes successfully.
However when I try to execute something inside my notebook I get a `FileNotFoundError` like

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/requests_data_query.sql'
```

So what is the best way to make paths visible at all the directories inside the project?

Comment: What do yo mean by `notebook`?

Comment: @MYousefi I want to import something inside notebook. So when you run a notebook your current dir is `./notebooks`. And it's impossible to get data from file `.data/requests_data_query.sql`because there is no `data` directory inside `notebooks` dir

Comment: Are you using something like `Jupyter`?

Comment: @MYousefi yes, I use jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can run notebook and specify desirable work directory. So here it's possible to run it from the root directory

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=path_to_dir
```